# Show a Reactjs component within a .map function by assigning it an id

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**When I click on a button within a .map function, I just want it to be displayed the component that I clicked on, i do not to want repeated in all the others. In this moment the behavior of the component is as follows.**

[image]

**When i click the three dots, show the next component:**

[image]

**In this order of ideas, I want this to not happen, I just want the component to be shown on the card I clicked on**

In the code I have the following:

```
const [navOpened, setNavOpened] = React.useState(false);
    const handleBurgerClick = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setNavOpened(!navOpened);
    }
    list.map(({ image, titleHeader, price, description, requirements, state, uuid_property }, i) =>
<div className={`card  ${state == 1 ? '' : 'card-disabled '}`} key={`car-${i}`}>

    ... // <-- more lines of code
                <div style={{ display: 'contents', position: 'relative' }}>
                    <img src={mas} alt="" className="icon-top-rigth-card filter-white" onClick={handleBurgerClick} />
                    <ul className="nav-links" style={{ borderRadius: '5px', boxShadow: '1px 1px 3px black', color: '#000', position: 'absolute', background: 'white', listStyle: 'none', right: '16rem' }}>
                        {navOpened
                            ?
                            <div style={{ padding: '1rem 3rem' }}>
                                <p onClick={() => window.location.href = `${MY_PROPERTY_FORM}/${uuid_property}`}>Editar</p>
                                <p
                                    onClick={
                                        () => {
                                            console.log('uuid_property', uuid_property)
                                        }
                                    }
                                >
                                    {state == 1 ? 'Pausar' : 'Activar'}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            : ""
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            ... // <-- more lines of code
</div>
```

**
I really appreciate that you can help me**

Comment: Please tell me where do you get `navOpened`?

Comment: Hi @bhoodream i get the navOpened here: 
``const [navOpened, setNavOpened] = React.useState(false);``
and the handleBurguerClick is that:
``const handleBurgerClick = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setNavOpened(!navOpened);
    }``

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not specify what item is opened.

**The solution to your problem:**

1. rename `navOpened` to `navOpenedId`;
2. pass `id`, for example `car-${i}` (although indexes are bad for keys/ids), in `handleBurgerClick` and set to the `navOpenedId`;
3. on the render, check if the `id` (`car-${i}`) of the current item is equal to `navOpenedId` from the `state`.

**The example code:**

```js
const List = (props) => {
  const { items = [] } = props;
  const initialOpenedId = (items[0] || {}).id;
  const [openedItemId, setOpenedItemId] = React.useState(initialOpenedId);
  
  const renderItem = (item) => 
    <li 
      onClick={() => setOpenedItemId(item.id)} 
      className={item.id === openedItemId ? '_opened' : ''}
    >{item.name}</li>;
  
  return <ul>{items.map(renderItem)}</ul>;
}

const items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'first' },
  { id: 2, name: 'second' },
  { id: 3, name: 'third' }
];

ReactDOM.render(<List items={items} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li._opened {
  color: orange;
}

li._opened::after {
  content: ' - OPENED';
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @jaimeduque17 , I refactored the example code on `useState` approach, i hope now its better for you

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolver that was separate the next code lines into another component and include it within the map function:

```
                <div style={{ display: 'contents', position: 'relative' }}>
                    <img src={mas} alt="" className="icon-top-rigth-card filter-white" onClick={handleBurgerClick} />
                    <ul className="nav-links" style={{ borderRadius: '5px', boxShadow: '1px 1px 3px black', color: '#000', position: 'absolute', background: 'white', listStyle: 'none', right: '16rem' }}>
                        {navOpened
                            ?
                            <div style={{ padding: '1rem 3rem' }}>
                                <p onClick={() => window.location.href = `${MY_PROPERTY_FORM}/${uuid_property}`}>Editar</p>
                                <p
                                    onClick={
                                        () => {
                                            console.log('uuid_property', uuid_property)
                                        }
                                    }
                                >
                                    {state == 1 ? 'Pause' : 'Start'}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            : ""
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

After:

```
<ThreeDots
   onClickEdit={() => { window.location.href = 
   `${MY_PROPERTY_FORM}/${uuid_property}`; }}
   onClickAct={() => {localStorage.setItem('uuidProperty', `${uuid_property}`);
   setStates(state.toString())
   setMiddle(true)}}
   } />
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to deal with handleBurgerClick preventDefault interface's event to solve your problem. When you have a click event in one component within another, you need to stop the propagation of the outer component click if you have  clicked in the inner component. You can handle with this by changing your handle function like this:

```
handleBurgerClick(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    //handleSomething()
}
```

You can learn more about eventDefault in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault